# Sum of nested list without using SUM function (exercise)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a function that take the sum of each list and return individual values in a new single list. 
E.g

```
[[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]]
```

becomes

```
[15, 15, 15]
```

What I have so far:

```
def row_sums(square):
    total_list = []
    total = 0
    for i in square:
        for j in i: 
            total += j
        total_list.append(total)
    return total_list
```

But this just accumulates each list onto each other resulting in:

```
[15, 30, 45]
```

I'm not sure how to keep the sums for each list separate here. The SUM function is not allowed here as it's an exercise on nested loops.

Thanks.

Comment: set `total=0` inside the first `for` loop. Also make sure you post correctly indented code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset your `total` counter before starting each inside for.
Also, you don't need to declare it outside, because you will use it only inside.

```
def row_sums(square):
    total_list = []
    for i in square:
        total = 0
        for j in i: 
            total += j
        total_list.append(total)
    return total_list
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is you do not re-initialize the `total` variable after each loop. Instead, initialize `sum = 0` inside he first for-loop like so:

```
def row_sums(square):
    total_list = []
    for i in square:
        total = 0
        for j in i: 
            total += j
        total_list.append(total)
    return total_list
```

Comment: Makes sense. At least it was something very simple. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @RobertHemingway You are very welcome. If you liked my answer, please upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
>>> list = [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]] 
>>> import functools
>>> [functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, sublist, 0) for sublist in list]
[15, 15, 15]
```

I did't use `sum` :)

You can read more about `functools.reduce` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Edit: As Sevanteri pointed out in the comment, you can also use `[functools.reduce(int.__add__, sublist, 0) for sublist in list]`
(if you really want to drive your teacher mad!)

Comment: And since there is already a binary sum function for integers, you can just replace that lambda with `int.__add__`. :)

Comment: @Sevanteri Hahaha I like this idea!

Comment: using `int.__add__` looks a little ugly, I rather use `operator.add` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to zero your total for each list.

```
def row_sums(square):
    total_list = []
    total = 0
    for i in square:
       for j in i: 
          total += j
       total_list.append(total)
       total = 0
    return total_list
```

Answer (score 0):

To be different, flatten the lists and using a generator (assumes sublists are the same length):

```
def _notsum2(lists):
    per_yield = len(lists)
    total = 0
    for ind, next in enumerate(val for sublist in lists for val in sublist):
        if ind % per_yield == 0 and ind:
            yield total
            total = 0
        total += next
    yield total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]]
    print [g for g in _notsum2(li)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it using `map` and list comprehension as:

```
l=[[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]] 
a,b,c=[x for x in l]
map(lambda x,y,z:x+y+z, a,b,c)
```

Answer (score -2):

`[sum(i) for i in zip(*[[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]])]`

bultin zip func is what you exactly needed

Comment: the OP want to do it without `sum`, also want the sum of the elements in each sublist not a the combination with all sublist