# The sum of indexes within nested lists. Adding elements from separate lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just doing an exercise question as follows: Take a ' number square' as a parameter and returns a list of the **column sums**.

e.g

```
square = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

Result should be =

```
[28, 32, 36, 40]
```

What I have so far:

```
def column_sums(square):
    col_list = []
    for i in range(len(square)): 
        col_sum = 0
        for j in range(len(square[i])): 
            col_sum += square[j]
        col_list.append(col_sum)
    return col_list
```

So I think I have all the parameters laid out, with all the indexing correct, but I am stuck because I get an error

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Which shouldn't happen if I am referencing the element within the list I thought.

Also it's probably easier to use the SUM command here, but couldn't figure out a way to use it cleanly.

Adding elements from separate lists via indexing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of nested list without using SUM function (exercise)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842453/sum-of-nested-list-without-using-sum-function-exercise)

Comment: Change square[j] to square[i][j] that is the specific location of the square. Currently, you are typecasting a list to an integer

Answer (score 2):

A more simpler solution would be to *transpose* the list of lists with `zip` and take the `sum` across each new sublist:

```
def column_sums(square):
    return [sum(i) for i in zip(*square)]
```

`zip(*square)` *unpacks* the list of lists and returns all items from each column (*zipped* as tuples) in successions.

```
>>> column_sums(square)
[28, 32, 36, 40]
```

---

You could also use [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to do this by setting the `axis` parameter to `0`, meaning sum along rows (i.e. sum on each column):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> square = np.array(square)
>>> square.sum(axis=0)
array([28, 32, 36, 40])
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `col_sum += square[j][i]` since you want to access the element at position `j` of the list at position `i`.

Comment: Hmm but with that addition it just gives me back the sum of each list
e.g `[10, 26, 42, 58]` to the above statement

Comment: That gives you the row sums not the column sums

Comment: Just swap the indices to get the col sum and not the row sum

Answer (score 1):

You should change the line of summing to:

```
col_sum += square[j][i]
```

because square[j] is the `j'th` row (list), but you need the current column, which is the `i'th` element in that row.

But here is my solution using `sum` and list comprehensions:

```
def column_sums2(square):
    def col(i):
        return [row[i] for row in square]
    return [sum(col(i)) for i in range(len(square))]
```